# ExtJs form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs

I have this form in ExtJs. If field1 is not empty, field2 must not be empty. But it is not working even though the listener is firing.

```
 {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'title 1',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'field A',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Line 1',
            id: 'field1',
            listeners: {
                change: function(f, new_val) {
                    if (new_val) {
                        //alert("change" + new_val);
                        f.field2.allowBlank = false;
                    } else {
                        f.field1.allowBlank = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            code for field2
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer:

The reason your code doesn't work is because allowBlank is a **configuration value** -- it only has an effect at the time the component is created.  I see this mistake all the time -- when browsing the API docs, you need to keep in mind that all those configuration options are only potent at object creation -- they are not public properties that you can set to modify behavior of an existing object.

That said, I'm surprised that there's no setAllowBlank() method in the API.  I'll continue to look around and amend this answer if I'm able to find a way to do it.

**EDIT**: It appears your method *should* work, from my reading of the TextField source code.  So the question is why isn't it.

**EDIT2**: You're probably failing to get a reference to your TextFields. `f.field1` is probably not pointing at what you think it is.  You can solve this by adding a `ref:'field1'` to your TextField config.  Then your FormPanel will have a property called field1 you can reference.

Comment: I agree that allowBlank is a config value and it should be used as such, but you can still use it as though it was a property. I did it on my previous project, and I was able to get the desired functionality that the OP describes. Now I just need to wait until I get home to remember how to do it :P. Don't get me wrong though, the code was definitely a kludge.

Comment: @McStretch - it looks like you're right.  Just had a peek at the code, and indeed the internals of TextField just inspect this.allowBlank when validating.  The docs should probably list it as a public property, not a mere config option.

Comment: I think the developers intended for it to be read only, but there are some cases where it's useful to modify the property on the fly; such as the OP's case. So yeah I agree, it should probably be a property unless there's a clearer way to develop this functionality.

Comment: @McStretch - Yeah, I don't see any obvious way around it.  It's used quite simply (and redundantly, interestingly enough) around line 452 of TextField.js

Answer (score 2):

You can use the markInvalid function.  For example:

```
if (new_val) {
    if(f.field2.getValue() == ''){
        f.field2.markInvalid('Cannot be empty');
    }
} else {
    // clears invalid flags on the field.
    f.field1.clearInvalid();
}
```

Not saying this is the exact code to use but you can see from this how to mark invalid and clear invalid messages.  There is also the capability of creating your own validators though I am not sure that would completely fit your needs.